# Error Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING - deserialization of an object inside of the string

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have a `json` string:

```
{
"Id": 1,
"Title": "A night with king of France",
"Description": "King's of France awesome audition",
"Day": "Monday",
"Time": "00:00:00",
"FinnishTime": "02:00:00",
"Picture": "http://cp91279.biography.com/1000509261001/1000509261001_1134394072001_Bio-Biography-Louis-XIV-LF-retry.jpg",
"Host1": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Louis XIV",
    "Description": "The king of France - likes classical music"
}}
```

and I'm trying to deserialize it using `json`

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<Program>() {}.getType();
Program h = new Gson().fromJson(text, listType);
```

My Program Class looks like this:

```
private int Id;
private String Title;
private String Description;
private String Day;
private LocalTime Time;
private LocalTime FinnishTime;
private String Picture;
private Host Host1;

Program(int id, String title, String description, Host host, String day, LocalTime startTime, LocalTime finnishTime, String picture)

{
    this.Id = id;
    this.Title = title;
    this.Description = description;
    this.Day = day;
    this.Time = startTime;
    this.FinnishTime = finnishTime;
    this.Picture = picture;
    this.Host1 = host;

}

public int getId() {
    return Id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    Id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return Title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    Title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return Description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    Description = description;
}

public Host getHost1() {
    return Host1;
}

public void setHost1(Host host1) {
    Host1 = host1;
}
public String toString() {
    return this.Id + ". " + this.Title;
}

public String getDay() {
    return Day;
}

public void setDay(String day) {
    Day = day;
}

public LocalTime getTime() {
    return Time;
}

public void setTime(LocalTime time) {
    Time = time;
}

public LocalTime getFinnishTime() {
    return FinnishTime;
}

public void setFinnishTime(LocalTime finnishTime) {
    FinnishTime = finnishTime;
}

public String getPicture() {
    return Picture;
}

public void setPicture(String picture) {
    Picture = picture;
```

EDIT

```
    private int Id;
private String Name;
private String Description;
public Host(int Id, String Name, String Description)
{
    this.Id = Id;
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Description = Description;
}

public int getId() {
    return Id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.Id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.Name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return Description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.Description = description;
}
```

The error is `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 120`
I think that the problem is that it confuses `Host1` variable with one of the others - but I have no idea why, and how to make it understand in correct way. What does line 1 column 120 mean?

Comment: where is `Host` class ?

Comment: @Abhishek Bansa l can post it just a second

Comment: please do it.. is it inner class or independent class ?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal ok, so I posted it, well it's independent class, but I deserialized it with success in the past, now I added some fields to Program class and I'm getting this error

Comment: can you try this `Program h = new Gson().fromJson(text, Program.class);`

Comment: @AbhishekBansal well, I just tried - didnt help

Comment: yes i think vandaics's answer is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a custom Type Adapter!

Try in this way:

```
        JsonDeserializer<LocalTime> localTimeDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<LocalTime>() {

            @Override
            public LocalTime deserialize(JsonElement jsonElem, Type type,
                    JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

                if (jsonElem == null) {
                    return null;
                }

                String localTimeStr = jsonElem.getAsString();
                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
                LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(localTimeStr, formatter);
                return localTime;
            }
        };

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                          .registerTypeAdapter(LocalTime.class, localTimeDeserializer).create();

        Type listType = new TypeToken<Program>() {}.getType();
        Program program = gson.fromJson(json, listType);
```

Comment: I just did it a second ago. But thank you very much. Actually I don't now which answer should I mark as solving one.

Comment: vandaics's answer is a workaround, it is not the solution of the problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

line 1 column 120 is `"Time": "00:00:00",` you should use String for `Time` and `FinnishTime`

Comment: But LocalTime provides me with some crucial funcionality - is there no way to deserialize it?

Comment: I don't do that ever. But you can get it by using `DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")` and `(Date)formatter.parse(yourobject.getTime())`